# How to use On input using VueJs and Laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vue.js

I followed along [this tutorial](http://taha-sh.com/blog/setting-up-ajax-validation-with-laravel-vuejs-in-no-time) and it worked perfectly fine. But what I want is to not use `submit` button to check or perform the validation, what I want is while I'm typing, it is now validating the form. Please see my code below, or visit the link that I mentioned above.

**Code:**

*routes*

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/article/create', 'ArticleController@showArticleCreationForm');
Route::post('/article', 'ArticleController@publish');
```

*ArticleController*

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function showArticleCreationForm(){
        return view('article.create');
    }

    public function publish(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'body' => 'required|min:10'
        ]);
        if ($request->ajax()) return;

        return 'publish';
    }
}
```

*create.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Article</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .body {
            height: 200px !important;
        }

        .error {
            color: darkred;
            margin-top: 5px;
            display: block;
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body id="app">
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" action="{{ URL::to('/') }}/article" method="post">
        <h1>Create New Article</h1>
        <hr>

        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" v-model="formInputs.title">
            <span v-if="formErrors['title']" class="error">@{{ formErrors['title'] }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control body" name="body" placeholder="Content" v-model="formInputs.body"></textarea>
            <span v-if="formErrors['body']" class="error">@{{ formErrors['body'] }}</span>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.6.1/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: {
            formInputs: {},
            formErrors: {}
        },

        methods: {
            submitForm: function(e){
                var form = e.target;
                var action = form.action;
                var csrfToken = form.querySelector('input[name="_token"]').value;

                this.$http.post(action, this.formInputs, {
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                  }
                })
                .then(function() {
                      form.submit();
                })
                .catch(function (data, status, request) {
                  var errors = data.data;
                  this.formErrors = errors;
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want validation (which is ajax) with onenter then you might also want to do it with some debounce. Then it's fine. Just decouple article creation from validation and create additional route for just validation.

Comment: @dfsq Hi. Can you provide your answer explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate while typing you should add  an `@keyup` (or `v-on:keyup`) event listener on your inputs and validate when it's triggered e.g:

```
<input class="form-control title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" v-model="formInputs.title" v-on:keyup="validate">
```

And your event listener:

```
 methods: {
      validate: function (e) {
            //e.target would have the target input which is being changed 

            _.debounce(function () {
                    var input = e.target;
                    var form = input.form;
                    var action = form.action; 
                    var csrfToken = form.querySelector('input[name="_token"]').value;

                    this.$http.post(action, this.formInputs, {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                    }
                 })
                .then(function() {
                      // Don't submit
                 })
                .catch(function (data, status, request) {
                    var errors = data.data;
                    this.formErrors = errors;
                });

            }.bind(this), 500); 
      }
```

This example uses [`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) which is a lodash function but you can easily write something similar yourself via `setTimeout` and `cancelTimeout` (lodash is just a convenience). The purpose is to not trigger validation on every keyup but rather spread it around a bit.

Comment: Hi. Is there any other way than this? so I can still use the `submitForm` method that I've created?

Comment: You can use the same method, but just not call `.submit` if it passes. Check the update.

Comment: `ReferenceError: _ is not defined` and 
`TypeError: e is undefined`

Comment: *This example uses _.debounce which is a lodash function but you can easily write something similar yourself via setTimeout and cancelTimeout (lodash is just a convenience). The purpose is to not trigger validation on every keyup but rather spread it around a bit.* I did mention this.

Comment: I got it now. But it still return an error in console. `TypeError: e is undefined`

Comment: Could try `v-on:keyup='validate($event)'` but it shouldn't be necessary normally. `e` is the event which is passed to the event handler by default

Comment: Oh, that's great! nice nice.

Comment: Can i ask one more thing?  What if I want the only input that I'm currently typing on to be validate only, not the other fields. Because when I'm typing on 1 field, it returns all the error.

Comment: You'd need to modify your `publish` function to only validate the field you give it. However you should consider using a Vue validation library like e.g. https://github.com/kazupon/vue-validator

Comment: Oh, great. I'm gonna check that one